# QGIS: Legend with more columns in one row

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I have two layers (`water_supply_design`, `water_supply_condition`). I'd like to create new map with Map Composer in QGIS. In this map, I'd like to have a legend with one row and two columns (`Water supply`, `design`, `state`). Is it possible to generate from this two layers a legend in that form?

[image: Legend illustration - first row is state, second row is proposal of the same item (roads in this case)]

Is this possible to create in the map composer?

Answer (score 11):

In the QGIS map composer, under **Legend Items**, you can specify the number of columns that you want in your legend e.g.:

[image]

Which will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can't have two symbols for one legend item but you can create (duplicate) two (or more) legends in the print composer and place one above each other with appropriate shift/spacing settings to achieve that effect. Example from print composer:

[image]